# Archiving SharePoint Pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem

Is there a specific way to approach archiving in SharePoint? For ex., archiving pages, lists, libraries.

If so, what is the best way for someone new to handling something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could check these two official documents to see if it helps:

[Use a SharePoint Server records archive or manage records in place](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/use-a-records-archive-or-manage-records-in-place)

[Choose how to store and manage records](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-how-to-store-and-manage-records-5299e96c-00ea-47dc-a711-f21b3cea00d3)

And here is a similar post:
[SharePoint 2016 Archiving feature](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08dbfe9e-c6c8-4ff8-bed7-97d354a2c475/sharepoint-2016-archiving-feature?forum=sharepointadmin)